# sqlite too slow for a single query

Tags: sqlite

I have a table named Rain which has about 10000 rows with the following schema:

> CREATE TABLE Rain(Country TEXT, Product Text, Date Date, Pr24 REAL)
>
> AR|CORN|1998-01-01 00:00:00|18.47319984
>   AR|CORN|1998-01-02 00:00:00|1.517950058
>   AR|CORN|1998-01-03 00:00:00|1.34533
>   AR|CORN|1998-01-04 00:00:00|7.247509956
>   AR|CORN|1998-01-05 00:00:00|6.925020218

Now for every row int the table I want to calculate the total rainfall of the year till the `Date` of the row. I execute the following code in the sqlte3 interpreter:

```
CREATE TABLE result AS  
SELECT Country, Product, Date,   
(SELECT SUM(Pr24) FROM Rain AS tmpTb  
    WHERE tmpTb.Date BETWEEN datetime(Rain.Date, 'start of year') AND Rain.Date)   
    AND tmpTb.Country = Rain.Country AND tmpTb.Product = Rain.Product
) AS Rainfall  
FROM Rain
```

but it takes about 4~5 hours to finish which is not acceptable.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database has to scan all rows for each execution of the subquery.
In other words, you have about 100,000,000 row accesses.

An index would allow searching for rows faster.
For this query, a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) would be optimal:

```
CREATE INDEX whatever ON Rain(Country, Product, Date, Pr24);
```

Comment: would create an index on all columns help?